# Safely redirect to a $_GET variable using header()

Tags: php, security, header

I am going through a current login system and there's a redirect carried out after a successful login simply using `header("Location: ".$_POST['url']);`. The `$_POST['url']` itself is set from the `$_GET['url']` parameter in a hidden field when the form is loaded.

As you can see there is an obvious way to hijack the user and maybe even get them to login to a phishing site.

Is there a foolproof, easy way to prevent hijacking from the `$_POST['url']`? My initial trail of thought would be something like `basename()` but sometimes the desired page is within a directory, so this would not work.

Comment: Why would you determine the redirection destination of a login page by either POST or GET?

Comment: It's the original desired location that is specified, eg, try upload.php, get redirected to login.php?url=upload.php. And I didn't design this but I need to secure it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set the redirect URL in the user session, and redirect the user to that URL after the successful login. This way the URL can't be hijacked.

Comment: A predefined constant or configuration variable can be used as well.

Answer (score 3):

I think the most secure way would be to use only the part after the domain name and make a whitelist of files / directories that are allowed and check against these.

Answer (score 1):

Use `parse_url()` to get `PHP_URL_PATH` and `PHP_URL_QUERY` parts, and redirect to relative path.

But it'll better to store redirect links in session.

Answer (score 0):

It will be from POST variables using that code, not GET variables. However, neither is any more 'secure' in the sense that both can be faked with relative ease. If you are concerned about the value(s) that might be passed, you will need to validate them in some way. If there is only a small handful of possible URLs, just check if the value is `in_array()` and redirect to a default location if not.

I'm not sure what you are concerned about happening, though. Couldn't a user just type in any URL in their address bar? What good would it be to redirect yourself to another URL *this* way? Unless this software relies on `HTTP_REFERER` for security...which would also not be secure.

Comment: An attacker could send someone a link to the login page with a redirect to a phishing site which could be an exact copy of my login form, but with a "try again" message, users would then put their login info into the attackers website.